# Return cumulated string from this recursive loop

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to return a final string which is concatenation of each nested object's string values. I'm not able to get it right.

I think I have some idea as whats happening; the issue is that `return` is called every time without checking for condition, as a result when the function calls itself, the variable `_text` becomes empty again. What condition should I check for `return` statement.

The `input` is just an example, the array contain any number of items and each item can be a string, object or array. Please help. Thanks for your time

```
var input = ["\n\t  This function constructs a named and protected temporal collection \n\t  in the schema database with the specified system and valid axes.  \n\t  This function assumes that the system and valid axes already exist.  \n\t  The temporal collection is stored in the Security database.  \n\t  ", {
    "p": {
        "_children": ["A TEMPORAL-DUPCOLLECTION exception is thrown if the collection \n          already exists.  "]
    }
}, {
    "p": {
        "_children": ["\n  For details on how to create a collection, see  \n ", {
            "a": {
                "_attributes": {
                    "href": "#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/6.0doc/xml/temporal/temporal-quick-start.xml%2366392"
                },
                "_children": ["Create a Temporal Collection"]
            }
        }, " in the ", {
            "em": {
                "_children": ["Temporal Developer's Guide"]
            }
        }]
    }
}];



function cleanupString(str) {
    return str.replace(/(\n|\t|\s+)/g, " ").trim();
}

function parseSummary(text, item) {
   // console.log('RAW-----:' + JSON.stringify(item))

    var _text =  text || '';

    if (typeof item === 'string') {
        _text = _text + item;
        _text = cleanupString(_text);
    } 
        // if item is object
    else if (item.constructor == Object) {
        for (var key in item) {
           return parseSummary(_text, item[key]);
        }
    } // if item is array
    else if (item.constructor == Array) {
        item.map(function(k) {
            return parseSummary(_text, k);
        });
    } 


        console.log('___TEXT____', _text);                      
        // I think the because of this return being called prematurely, the 
        // variable _text is reset to empty, but not sure what condition I 
        // should check  because there is no way of knowing if its reached end 
        // of the object 
        return _text; 

}
var summary = parseSummary('', input);
console.log('SUMMARY:', summary); // comes out as empty
```

**log**

```
 ___TEXT____ This function constructs a named and protected temporal collection in the schema database with the specified system and valid axes. This function assumes that the system and valid axes already exist. The temporal collection is stored in the Security database.
 ___TEXT____ A TEMPORAL-DUPCOLLECTION exception is thrown if the collection already exists.
 ___TEXT____ 
 ___TEXT____ For details on how to create a collection, see
 ___TEXT____ #display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/6.0doc/xml/temporal/temporal-quick-start.xml%2366392
 ___TEXT____ in the
 ___TEXT____ Temporal Developer's Guide
 ___TEXT____ 
 ___TEXT____ 
 ___TEXT____ 
 SUMMARY:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but clearly, you are not handling the return values of the recursion properly.  Perhaps you mean this:

```
function parseSummary(text, item) {
    var _text =  text || '';

    if (typeof item === 'string') {
        _text = _text + cleanupString(item);
    } else if (item.constructor == Object) {
        for (var key in item) {
          _text = parseSummary(_text, item[key]);
        }
    } else if (item.constructor == Array) {
        item.map(function(k) {
          _text = parseSummary(_text, k);
        });
    } 
    return _text; 
}
```

Comment: Why bother with `text` at all? The function doesn't really need an input text.

Comment: I thought he might have some reason for passing it down.  Like I said, I do not grasp the underlying intent, so I did not want to screw with his code too much.

Comment: aah! ` _text = parseSummary()` was what I was missing. That fixed my code. Thanks a lot Malvolio!
btw I used `input` is just for the sake of demo, but I need the funtion to take input variable in my overall code.

Answer (score 0):

Like you say, you're returning out of the function early. What you want is probably something more like

```
function parseSummary(item) {
    var _text = '';

    if (typeof item === 'string') {
        _text = cleanupString(item);
    } // if item is object
    else if (item.constructor == Object) {
        for (var key in item) {
           _text += parseSummary(item[key]);
        }
    } // if item is array
    else if (item.constructor == Array) {
        item.map(function(k) {
            _text += parseSummary(k);
        });
    } 
    return _text; 
}
```

```js
var input = ["\n\t  This function constructs a named and protected temporal collection \n\t  in the schema database with the specified system and valid axes.  \n\t  This function assumes that the system and valid axes already exist.  \n\t  The temporal collection is stored in the Security database.  \n\t  ", {
    "p": {
        "_children": ["A TEMPORAL-DUPCOLLECTION exception is thrown if the collection \n          already exists.  "]
    }
}, {
    "p": {
        "_children": ["\n  For details on how to create a collection, see  \n ", {
            "a": {
                "_attributes": {
                    "href": "#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/6.0doc/xml/temporal/temporal-quick-start.xml%2366392"
                },
                "_children": ["Create a Temporal Collection"]
            }
        }, " in the ", {
            "em": {
                "_children": ["Temporal Developer's Guide"]
            }
        }]
    }
}];



function cleanupString(str) {
    return str.replace(/(\n|\t|\s+)/g, " ").trim();
}

function parseSummary(item) {
    var _text = '';
    
    if (typeof item === 'string') {
        _text = cleanupString(item);
    } // if item is object
    else if (item.constructor == Object) {
        for (var key in item) {
           _text += parseSummary(item[key]);
        }
    } // if item is array
    else if (item.constructor == Array) {
        item.map(function(k) {
            _text += parseSummary(k);
        });
    } 
    return _text; 
}
var summary = parseSummary(input);
console.log('SUMMARY:', summary); // comes out as empty
```